# T-sql help to switch dates on the SSRS report

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I've a requirement per below business rule to change the Scheduled Delivery Date on the report. Below is the DDL:

1) If the Job has a batch number, the Scheduled Ship Date will be next monday to Requested Delivery Date. Say for example if the job has Requested Delivery Date as 2015-07-29 and it also has a batch number then Scheduled Ship Date will be 2015-08-03.

2) If the Job does not have a batch number then the Scheduled Ship Date will be the Monday before the REquested Delivery Date. Say for example if the Job J012347 has Requested Delivery date as 2015-08-04 and it does not have batch number then the Scheduled Ship Date will be the Monday before i.e. 2015-08-04.

Similarly if the Requested Delivery date is 2015-08-07 and it does not have a batch number then Scheduled Delivery Date will be 2015-08-03.

Can we achieve this? I appreciate any help on this.

Hope this helps

Here is the DDL:

```
DECLARE @Date datetime;
SET @Date = GETDATE();

DECLARE @TEST_DATA TABLE
(
    DT_ID INT       IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
   ,JobNumber       VARCHAR(10)   NOT NULL
   ,JobStatus       CHAR(1)       NOT NULL
   ,ExpectedDate    VARCHAR(10)   NOT NULL
   ,LastShippedDate VARCHAR(10)       NULL
   ,BatchNumber VARCHAR(10)         NULL
);

INSERT INTO @TEST_DATA (JobStatus, JobNumber,ExpectedDate,LastShippedDate, BatchNumber) 
VALUES
 ('S', 'J012345','2015-07-10','2015-07-10', 'B001')
,('S', 'J012346','2015-07-15','2015-07-17', 'B001')
,('S', 'J012346','2015-07-17','2015-07-15', 'B002')
,('S', 'J012346','2015-07-08','2015-07-10', 'B002')
,('O', 'J012347','2015-08-04',NULL, NULL)
,('O', 'J012347','2015-07-24',NULL, 'B003')
,('O', 'J012347','2015-07-31',NULL, 'B003')
,('O', 'J012347','2015-07-27',NULL, 'B004')
,('O', 'J012348','2015-07-21',NULL, 'B004')
,('O', 'J012349','2015-07-31',NULL,  NULL)
,('O', 'J012350','2015-08-07',NULL,  NULL)
,('O', 'J012351','2015-08-14',NULL,  NULL)
,('O', 'J012362','2015-08-28',NULL, 'B004')
,('O', 'J012363','2015-07-22',NULL, 'B005')
,('O', 'J012364','2015-07-24',NULL, NULL)
,('O', 'J012365','2015-07-31',NULL, NULL)
,('O', 'J012366','2015-08-21',NULL, 'B006')
,('O', 'J012372','2015-07-27',NULL, 'B007')
,('O', 'J012378','2015-07-29',NULL, 'B008')
,('O', 'J012367','2015-08-11',NULL, NULL)
,('O', 'J012367','2015-07-30',NULL, NULL)
,('O', 'J012367','2015-09-18',NULL, 'B006')
;

SELECT 
    J.DT_ID
    ,JobNumber
   ,J.JobStatus /*O-Open, S-Shipped, I-Invoiced*/
   ,J.ExpectedDate 'Requested Delivery Date'
   ,J.LastShippedDate
   , BatchNumber
   ,CASE
        /* SHIPPED - SHOW LastShippedDate */
        WHEN j.JobStatus  ='S' OR j.JobStatus  ='I' OR j.JobStatus  ='V'  THEN Cast(j.LastShippedDate as DATE)
        /* MISSED SHIPMENT SET TO NEXT MONDAY */
        WHEN j.JobStatus <>'S'  AND DATEDIFF(dd,0,ExpectedDate)/7 <= DATEDIFF(dd,0,@Date) / 7 THEN
            DATEADD(DAY,((DATEDIFF(dd,0,@Date)/7) * 7) + 7,0)
        /* FUTURE SHIPMENTS */
        --ELSE CAST(J.ExpectedDate AS DATE)
        ELSE DATEADD(DAY,((DATEDIFF(dd,0,J.ExpectedDate)/7) * 7) + 7,0)
    END AS [Scheduled Ship Date],

    DATENAME(dw, J.ExpectedDate) AS ExpectedDateDayName,
    DATENAME(dw, CASE
            WHEN j.JobStatus  ='S' OR j.JobStatus  ='I' OR j.JobStatus  ='V'  THEN Cast(j.LastShippedDate as DATE)
            WHEN j.JobStatus <>'S' AND DATEDIFF(dd,0,ExpectedDate)/7 <= DATEDIFF(dd,0,@Date) / 7 THEN
                DATEADD(DAY,((DATEDIFF(dd,0,@Date)/7) * 7) + 7,0)
            --ELSE CAST(J.ExpectedDate AS DATE)
            ELSE DATEADD(DAY,((DATEDIFF(dd,0,J.ExpectedDate)/7) * 7) + 7,0)
        END) AS ScheduledShipDateDayName

FROM @TEST_DATA AS J
ORDER BY [Requested Delivery Date]
```

Comment: Points for showing Code. So if it has a batch num, it will be the shipped the monday following the requested delivery date? So late..?

Comment: @Holmes IV-Yes, if it has the batch number Scheduled Delivery date will be following Monday to Requested Delivery Date. If the job does not have a batch number Scheduled Delivery date will show the Monday before the Requested Delivery Date. Hope this helps. Thanks

Comment: What's wrong with the code you have?   Are you getting an error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you are trying to find "next monday" if there is not a batch and if there is one the previous monday to the request date:

```
Select Case when BatchNumber is not null then  
                case when datepart(dw,J.ExpectedDate) > 1 then DATEADD(dd,9-DATEPART(dw,J.ExpectedDate),J.ExpectedDate)
                    else DATEADD(dd,1,J.ExpectedDate) end 
        Else dateadd(ww,-2, case when datepart(dw,J.ExpectedDate) > 1 then DATEADD(dd,9-DATEPART(dw,J.ExpectedDate),J.ExpectedDate)
                else DATEADD(dd,1,J.ExpectedDate) end) end AS [Scheduled Ship Date]


FROM @TEST_DATA AS J
```

Comment: -For this jobnumber (,('O', 'J012362','2015-08-28',NULL, 'B004')) I get ScheduledShipDate as 2015-08-31 instead of 2015-08-24. Any inputs? Thanks

Comment: weird i don't know why, it has to be to with the end of the month, *note i just fix some of the math still same results.